# Intrinsically versus necessarily

Tags: logic, ethics, modal-logic

> The weakest normal [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), named K in honor of Saul Kripke, is
>   simply the propositional calculus augmented by □, the rule N, and the
>   axiom K. K is weak in that it fails to determine whether a proposition
>   can be necessary but only contingently necessary. That is, it is not a
>   theorem of K that if □p is true then □□p is true, i.e., that necessary
>   truths are "necessarily necessary".

So perhaps what is necessary isn't necessarily necessary.

But what about intrinsicality? If something is intrinsic, is that a fact intrinsic to what it is intrinsic to?

> Lewis has in several places (1983a, 1986a, 1988) insisted that shape
>   properties are [intrinsic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intrinsic-extrinsic/), but one could hold that an object's shape
>   depends on the curvature of the space in which it is embedded, and
>   this might not even be intrinsic to that space (Nerlich 1979)

But it is easy to imagine that shape is an intrinsic property of what has a shape. So is e.g. is it an intrinsic fact about an object that it intrinsically has its shape? And what would that mean?

I am asking because I assume that all intrinsic obligations are intrinsically rational.

Assuming that, *perhaps* claiming that everything intrinsically rational was intrinsically valuable, would [practically](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/supplement.html) make it intrinsically rational that any [value](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/26753/is-moral-value-innate-or-just-non-accidental) is intrinsically rational.

- And would that mean all intrinsic value is self-evident?

Comment: I'm getting stuck on "intrinsically rational" -- is this your construction? (in which case could you further develop that idea?) or is it present in a pre-existing stream of philosophical thought (in which case that usage should be indicated)?

Comment: Mathematicians have in fact thought long and hard about the nature of equivalence relations and models.  I wish someone would just take those notions to heart, instead of focussing on weak notions that are not used daily.

Comment: @Dave hey sorry to be a pain... the term appears in the literature, but i don't know of any definition. i'll look

Comment: hi i edited the question to reflect it is my own construction - just a quality that all intrinsic obligation (may) have

Comment: @Mathematician Each modal logic is a formalized calculus. In addition, its concept of necessity can be given an interpretation as "holding in all possible worlds". Now analogously: What is your intended meaning of the terms *intrinsic*, *valuable*, *rational* and of *intrinsically rational*? For me it is not standard what the intended meanings of these terms are. Also *self-evident* is a problematic term.

Comment: @JoWehler i hope i've clarified "rational" with my last edit. i don't know how to clarify "value". "intrinsic" i thought was implied in the SEP article i linked to. you are ofc welcome to work around the question in any answer ?

Comment: @Mathematician I apologize, but where do you state your meaning of the term *rational*?

Comment: @JoWehler hey, i just meant how it is that we are practically obliged toward what is valuable ?? sorry if i seem crazy or stupid

Comment: "*We have some of our properties purely in virtue of the way we are. We have other properties in virtue of the way we interact with the world. The former are the intrinsic properties, the latter are the extrinsic properties*". I am not sure why Lewis takes shape as intrinsic, it changes under pressure, etc. Shape is not intrinsic in geometry either, you can bend a sheet of paper without changing its surface metric, but curvature is, it stays 0. It seems intrinsic can be formalized as invariant in some sense, not changing under some class of transformations, but it is relative to that class.

Comment: Modal logic has duality between possibility and neccessity; and given Conifolds comment, intrinsic and extrinsic appear to be a dual pair; but is it possible to formalise this duality, as it has been done already for the traditional [alethic modal logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic); as well as doxastic (belief),  deontic (duty), and epistemic (knowledge)?

Comment: The intrinsic/extrinsic pair doesn't appear to fit into this schema; maybe it's an additional one - a modal logic of *essences*? Since for a property that is intrinsic, is one that is essential; and one that is extrinsic, is accidental ie non-essential.

Comment: If the traditional means of duality works here, we would have: E p = not [I (not p)]; but does this even make sense?